# how to give track value (letter spacing between characters) in folios

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, letterspacing

My requirement is, need to give positive track (i.e., increase letterspacing between characters) in running heads and folios (page numbers), for this I'm using the below code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,soul}

\sodef\RHtrack{}{0.95pt}{4pt}{5pt}%

\makeatletter
  \def\ps@headings{
\def\@oddfoot{\relax}%
\def\@evenfoot{\relax}%%
      \def\@evenhead{\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont{{\thepage}}\ignorespaces\hspace*{7\p@}\ignorespaces{\MakeUppercase\leftmark}\hfill}%
      \def\@oddhead{\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont\hfill{\MakeUppercase\rightmark}\ignorespaces\hspace*{7\p@}\ignorespaces{\thepage}}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\RHtrack{##1}}{\RHtrack{##1}}}%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{101}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is working fine for the running head only but for the folios it doesn't work, please suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\ignorespaces` don't do anything there. I just removed them. For the page to be displayed spaced you have to expand the number before you give it to `\RHtrack`. The following does so using `\romannumeral` to expand `\thepage` as much as possible (it fails for `Roman`, `alph` and `Alph` numbering though).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,soul}

\sodef\RHtrack{}{0.95pt}{4pt}{5pt}%

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings
  {%
    \def\@oddfoot{\relax}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\relax}%%
    \def\@evenhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \expandafter\RHtrack\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\thepage}%
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \MakeUppercase{\leftmark}\hfill
      }%
    \def\@oddhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \hfill
        \MakeUppercase{\rightmark}%
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \expandafter\RHtrack\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\thepage}%
      }%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\RHtrack{##1}}{\RHtrack{##1}}}%
  }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{101}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using either pdfTeX or LuaTeX you could consider using `microtype` and its letterspacing:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings
  {%
    \def\@oddfoot{\relax}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\relax}%%
    \def\@evenhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \lsstyle
        \thepage
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \MakeUppercase{\leftmark}\hfill
      }%
    \def\@oddhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \lsstyle
        \hfill
        \MakeUppercase{\rightmark}%
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \thepage
      }%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
  }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{101}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

(Result looks pretty similar)

**Edit** Using `soul` and a temporary macro for the expansion using `\edef` one can get the solution using `soul` to work with every standard counter formatting there is in LaTeX (I hope I didn't forget one, I tested: `arabic`, `alph`, `Alph`, `roman`, `Roman`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,soul}

\sodef\RHtrack{}{0.95pt}{4pt}{5pt}%

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings
  {%
    \def\@oddfoot{\relax}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\relax}%%
    \def\@evenhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \begingroup
        \edef\tmp{\thepage}%
        \expandafter\RHtrack\expandafter{\tmp}%
        \endgroup
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \MakeUppercase{\leftmark}\hfill
      }%
    \def\@oddhead
      {%
        \fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont
        \hfill
        \MakeUppercase{\rightmark}%
        \hspace*{7\p@}%
        \begingroup
        \edef\tmp{\thepage}%
        \expandafter\RHtrack\expandafter{\tmp}%
        \endgroup
      }%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\RHtrack{##1}}{\RHtrack{##1}}}%
  }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{101}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: your suggestion works excellently, thanks a lot, please suggest that how can be implement this for alpha numericals for front matter part...thanks in advance...

Comment: @MadyYuvi The second solution works for every formatting of numbers, the first one for `arabic` and `roman`. I'll post an edit containing a third solution which should work for everything.

Comment: Excellent, all my issues are fixed, thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

Use `microtype` instead of `soul`.

The factor 500 is exaggerated, just to clearly show that tracking is actually done.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
  \def\@oddfoot{\relax}%
  \def\@evenfoot{\relax}%
  \def\@evenhead{\footnotesize\textls[500]{\thepage\hspace*{7\p@}\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}\hfill}%
  \def\@oddhead{\hfill\footnotesize\textls[500]{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}\hspace*{7\p@}\thepage}}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{##1}{##1}}%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{101}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]